# Too many calculated properties in my class

Tags: c#, properties

I have class which have too many related calculated properties.

I have currently kept all properties are read only.

some properties need long calculation and it is called again when its related properties are needed.

How can create this complex object .Also i want these properties should not  be set from external code. I need show hide as i am binding properties for UI. Also i think order is also important.
My Class is something like

```
     public string A
    {
        get
        {
            return complexMethod();
            ;
        }
    }
    public string B
    {
        get
        {
            if (A == "value")
                return "A";
            else return "B";
            ;
        }

    }

    public bool ShowHideA
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(A);
            ;
        }
    }

    public bool ShowHideB
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(B);
            ;
        }
    }


    public string complexMethod()
    {
        string value = "";
        // calculation goes here
        return value;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correct, you could use a lazy pattern.

Comment: Code? Where is it? It's a ninja?

Comment: What counts as "too many"? What are you trying to achieve here? Your question is pretty unclear - especially without any examples.

Comment: "what is memoization?" (i.e. cache the values when you first calculate them)

Comment: I have around 20 properties which comes from database. based on these values i calculate other properties around 30. Also i have show hide properties attached which depends on whether properties are empty or not

Comment: @user3855208 explain better what you want and show us what you've tried. This site is not a code take away

Comment: I *think* what you are after here is really just a once-only calculation; unless you have specific complicating factors, you can probably do this quite simply; for example: `double? stressFactor; public double StressFactor { get { return stressFactor ?? (stressFactor = (/* formula goes here */)); } }`

Comment: I have added code snipped to clarify my problem

Answer (score 0):

Well tall order isn't it?

One of the coolest things about extension methods is you can use types.  This is perfect for writing external programs to calculate property values.  Start like this...

```
public static class XMLibrary
{
    public static MC CalculateValues(this MC myclass)
    {
        //for each property calculate the values here
        if (myclass.Name == string.Empty) myclass.Name = "You must supply a name";
        if (myclass.Next == 0) myclass.Next = 1;
        //when done return the type
        return myclass;
    }
}

public class MC
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Next { get; set; }
}

public class SomeMainClass
{
    public SomeMainClass()
    {
        var mc = new MC { Name = "test", Next = 0 };
        var results = mc.CalculateValues();
    }
}
```

There are many other ways to do class validation on a model, for example dataannotations comes to mind, or IValidatableObject works too.  Keeping the validation separate from the class is a good idea.

```
//Complex properites are simple
public class MyComplextClass{
 public List<MyThings> MyThings {get;set;}
 public List<FileInfo> MyFiles {get;set;}
 public List<DateTime> MyDates {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Now, I'm willing to grant that the question is pretty vague and unclear - but I cannot see how this addresses the question. Or how it is expected to compile.

Comment: Did you try it?  I use this pattern every day. It works perfectly.  Sometimes showing advanced concepts requires a bit of digging in to understand.  In the example above I could have excluded the generic typing to make it easier.  I was only addressing his question of doing all the rules in some other area other than in the class at question, extension methods are perfect for this.  I'm here only to help not write a total solution.

Comment: firstly, no, the code as shown doesn't work *at all*, because it has at least 4 compile-time errors in it (and also completely fails to implement an extension method, despite the sentence before being about extension methods); however, before we can evaluate the question of whether or not it "works", we need to know *what it is meant to do*; let's *pretend* it was compiling code for a moment: *it still doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question*

Comment: Ok you are right, I corrected the code.  It should work fine and is a great example of using extension methods for validation or calculation. IMHO it is the implementation of cross-cutting concerns without Spring.NET nonsense.  Lean and ready to go.

Comment: As presented, there is absolutely no reason for this to be an extension method; it isn't a cross-cutting concern, and could be an instance method; however, it *still* IMO fails to address anything from the question

Comment: I respect your opinion.  For me this pattern works fantastic everyday.  It's cross-cutting to me because not one lick of code for business rules and or validation are contained in the model or view model itself [ok so I have to call it manually so what?].  Its magic, and fits in with "Open for extension, closed for modification  pattern"  But there's zero learning curve and complexity to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Lazy type provided by .net:

```
Lazy<YourType> lazy = new Lazy<YourType>();
```

Make your properties internal to not be set from external code.